# Python : How to shift the square plot in the x axis by a given value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

X = [0.3, 0.7, 0, 0.8]

I want to plot like below. But using general `plt.plot` I cannot like below.

Here I miss a logic to implement this ?

[image]

Comment: Do you have some script to purpose us ? ..

Comment: Yes, `plt.plot(X, marker='d', color='blue', drawstyle='steps-pre')`. This  din't give the proper result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this simple example will help you:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
values = (5, 7, 4, 9, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  
width = 0.35      

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, values, width, color='r')

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Y-label')
ax.set_title('X-label')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width)
ax.set_xticklabels(('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'))


def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)

plt.show()
```

> output:
>   [image]

Comment: This is a bar plot,  plotted the values . What I want is different from the one you posted. Please check my picture. In my case Y-axis value is 1 for given length in X.

Comment: So you want something like a Signal plot? Because it is not clear from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

After understanding that you want to plot a graph that looks like a binary signal graph, I came with that example you may find helpful:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import step, xlim, ylim, show
x = np.arange(0, 7)
y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
xlim(0, 7)
ylim(0, 1.5)
step(x, y)
show()
```

[image]